# List of Users ordered by the rank of their Posts reviews

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to make an `API End Point` so the user can get a list of the users in his city ordered by their post reviews

I have defined a method in the post model to calculate the total review (up vote and down vote), I'm imagining that the solution can be realized in the following path but I'm not entirely sure `groupBy post_owner` in the post and `orderBy sum(count_reactions())`, but I don't know how to do it in django

**Post Model**

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=255, default='Title')
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                             default='https://www.eltis.org/sites/default/files/styles/web_quality/public/default_images/photo_default_2.png')
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def count_reactions(self):
        likes_count = Reaction.objects.filter(post=self.id, is_like=True).count()
        dislikes_count = Reaction.objects.filter(post=self.id, is_like=False).count()
        return likes_count - dislikes_count

    def owner(self):
        return self.post_owner
```

**MyUser Model**

```py
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, unique=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='city', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def owner(self):
        return self
```

**Reaction Model**

```py
class Reaction(models.Model):
    reaction_owner = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='reactions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_like = models.BooleanField(null=False)

    def owner(self):
        return self.reaction_owner
```

The expected result is to get the ordered list of the users by their posts reviews but only the users in the same city (city field in `MyUser` model)

Comment: Not entirely clear what you want since first you talk about getting a list of users, then you talk about grouping posts by users and ordering them (and what is `count_review`? In your code there's `count_reactions`). But here's some hints: GROUP_BY in Django is done by using `.values()` and adding values to sort by is done by `.annotate()` with aggregation functions like `Sum()`. Look it up [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/)

Comment: that part is what I'm imagining the solution will be (or what I have tried to do) I'm not entirely sure about it .

Comment: Well show us what you’ve tried. It’ll make it easier to understand what query you’re looking for. But I really advise you to study carefully the page I linked. Best way is to use your python console to directly try your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [Navid's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8069748/navid-zarepak) answer but completing it with excluding the users with rank equal to zero and include also the limit

```py
# Filter for the city you want
users = MyUser.objects.filter(city=your_city_obj)

# Then doing the calculations
users = users.annotate(rank_point=(Count('post__reactions', filter=Q(post__reactions__is_like=True)) - (Count('post__reactions', filter=Q(post__reactions__is_like=False))))).filter(rank_point__gt=0)

# And finaly, order the results
users = users.order_by('-rank_point')[:LIMIT]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it all into one query.

Depending on where your `Reaction` naming the query should look something like this:

```
# Filter for the city you want
users = MyUser.objects.filter(city=your_city_obj)

# Then doing the calculations
users = users.annotate(rank_point=(Count('post__reactions', filter=Q(post__reactions__is_like=True)) - (Count('post__reactions', filter=Q(post__reactions__is_like=False)))))

# And finaly, order the results
users = users.order_by('-rank_point')
```

Comment: Question is edited so you can see the reaction model.

Comment: I think it should work or maybe the `post__reaction` should be changed to `post__reactions`. Give it a try and let me know if you got an error.

Comment: I got an Error `NameError: name 'post__reactions' is not defined`

Comment: I made a change, the `Count(post__reactions)` should be changed to `Count('post__reactions')`. also i tested the code and `post__reactions` is the correct name to use.

Comment: It works all fine right now, but how can extract only the users where the rank is greater than zero

Comment: You can add another filter after the annotation just like a normal query: `users.filter(rank_point__gt=0)`